# Safely remove usb from linux device

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device

I am using a USB with an embedded device running linux. The issue is that in some cases when I unmount the usb by giving the command `umount /media/sda1` the unmount is successful but when I proceed to remove the usb I get an error saying unable to mark fs as dirty and when I plug it back in I get the error  `Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.` Is there any other command on the linux terminal which I can use to safely eject the usb? so that the usb device is powered off before I unplug it.

Update: I tried using sync but the error is still there as shown below:

```
root@(none):~# sync
root@(none):~# umount /media/sda1
root@(none):~# ls /media/sda1
root@(none):~# [  296.021241] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  296.026879] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  296.031175] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]
[  296.033743] Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[  296.048283] FAT-fs (sda1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
```

Comment: You could try `sync`.

Comment: Are there any side effects as It says here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90657/how-to-remove-a-usb-drive-without-worrying-if-its-been-unmounted that 'sync is bad for lifetime of the device' and i am unsure about  the side effects of flush

Comment: Bad or not - what's the effect of not syncing? Corrupt files. The article you linked to suggests that `sync`ing each time you write to the device (for example after a few minutes of editing a document) is bad as you write too many times which in theory reduces the lifetime of the device. Syncing just before you `umount` is common sense as you want your data to be written to the device don't you?

Comment: as others mentioned, use `sync` before `umount`

Comment: @garethTheRed  Yes you are right i will try it with sync. Thanks

Comment: @garethTheRed I tried sync command but it had no effect i was getting the same error as edited in my post

Comment: FWIW, umount does a sync on the partition automatically.

Comment: Did you try @jimmij 's solution? It looks promising :-)

Comment: I came to this question because I wanted to know about "how to remove USB device of  **any** type" and not only USB mass storage/block device.

Answer (score 8):

`eject /dev/sda` will try and safely remove the device from the kernel and make it safe to remove.  You can verify it's removed by looking on /dev to see if the partition entry has been removed (the base device may still show up).

e.g. I just plugged in a USB stick and it showed as /dev/sdg and the partition as sdg1.  I can unmount it and it still shows, but after the eject it disappears

```
$ ls /dev/sdg*
/dev/sdg  /dev/sdg1

$ df | grep sdg
/dev/sdg1       59632764  47460364   9136496  84% /media/sweh/music

$ umount /dev/sdg1

$ ls /dev/sdg*
/dev/sdg  /dev/sdg1

$ sudo eject /dev/sdg

$ ls /dev/sdg*       
/dev/sdg
```

Comment: my linux version apparently doesn't have that command
 
root@(none):~# eject /dev/sda1
-sh: eject: command not found